# CPU memory access time

Tags: cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Does the average data and instruction access time of the CPU depends on the execution time of an instruction? 
For example if miss ratio is 0.1, 50% instructions need memory access,L1 access time 3 clock cycles, mis penalty is 20 and instructions execute in 1 cycles what is the average memory access time?

Comment: Nop trying to figure out what the lecture did.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assume you're talking about a CISC architecture where compute instructions can have memory references.  If you have a sequence of ADDs that access memory, then memory requests will come more often than a sequence of the same number of DIVs, because the DIVs take longer.  This won't affect the time of the memory access -- only locality of reference will affect the average memory access time.

If you're talking about a RISC arch, then we have separate memory access instructions.  If memory instructions have a miss rate of 10%, then the average access latency will be the L1 access time (3 cycles for hit or miss) plus the L1 miss penalty times the miss rate (0.1 * 20), totaling an average access time of 5 cycles.

If half of your instructions are memory instructions, then that would factor into clocks per instruction (CPI), which would depend on miss rate and also dependency stalls.  CPI will also be affected by the extent to which memory access time can overlap computation, which would be the case in an out-of-order processor.

I can't answer your question a lot better because you're not being very specific.  To do well in a computer architecture class, you will have to learn how to figure out how to compute average access times and CPI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll go ahead and answer your question, but then, please read my comments below to put things into a modern perspective:

```
Time = Cycles * (1/Clock_Speed)   [ unit check: seconds = clocks * seconds/clocks ]
```

So, to get the exact time you'll need to know the clock speed of your machine, for now, my answer will be in terms of Cycles

```
Avg_mem_access_time_in_cycles = cache_hit_time + miss_rate*miss_penalty
                              = 3 + 0.1*20 
                              = 5 cycles
```

Remember, here I'm assuming your miss rate of 0.1 means 10% of cache accesses miss the cache. If you're meaning 10% of instructions, then you need to halve that (because only 50% of instrs are memory ops).

Now, if you want the average CPI (cycles per instr)

```
CPI = instr% * Avg_mem_access_time + instr% * Avg_instr_access_time 
    = 0.5*5 + 0.5*1 = 3 cycles per instruction
```

Finally, if you want the average instr execution time, you need to multiply 3 by the reciprocal of the frequency (clock speed) of your machine.

Comments: 
Comp. Arch classes basically teach you a very simplified  way of what the hardware is doing. Current architectures are much much more complex and such a model (ie the equations above) is very unrealistic. For one thing, access time to various levels of cache can be variable (depending on where physically the responding cache is on the multi- or many-core CPU); also access time to memory (which typically 100s of cycles) is also variable depending on contention of resources (eg bandwidth)...etc. Finally, in modern CPUs, instructions typically execute in parallel (ILP) depending on the width of the processor pipeline. This means adding up instr execution latencies is basically wrong (unless your processor is a single-issue processor that only executes one instr at a time and blocks other instructions on miss events such as cache miss and br mispredicts...). However, for educational purpose and for "average" results, the equations are okay.

One more thing, if you have a multi-level cache hierarchy, then the miss_penalty of level 1 cache will be as follows:

```
L1$ miss penalty = L2 access time + L1_miss_rate*L2_miss_penalty
```

If you have an L3 cache, you do a similar thing to L2_miss_penalty and so on